# GpSysHook dll detected as virus

Tags: delphi

We use [GpSysHook](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/gpsyshook.htm)  to log keyboard and mouse events in our software. Unfortunately some anti virus programs detect the hook dll as a virus, as can easily be demonstrated by [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).
Does anybody have ideas how to change the dll so that it is no longer detected as a virus?
I already tried packing with upx without success.

UPDATE:
  Following @David and @Shamballa's suggestion I contacted McAfee. The only response so far was an automated reply mail, telling me that GpSysHookDll.dll is indeed malware and that they have it in their signature database. Apparently no human being actually looked at my mail.
So I had to do something about it myself, and indeed after some minor changes McAfee no longer suspects GpSysHookDll as malware. I would have never thought how easy it is to fool a virus scanner. The reason why I don't want to give an answer here about what I did is because it may eventually help bad people develop nasty software (Although I think they already now those simple tricks). I will rather contact the original author with my changes so he can update his otherwise excellent hook component.

Comment: @David, any idea whom to talk to at McAfee ? Will they even listen to me ?

Comment: I think they will. Have a look on their website for a means to submit false positives.

Comment: For McAfee send email to: virus_research@avertlabs.com NOTE: Make sure you zip up the file(s) and password protect it with the word infected. Even though it is not a virus this password must be contained on the zip file or they will ignore your email.

Comment: @David and Shambella Thanks for the info - I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Virusscanners work using signatures.
Usually using a hash (of the whole or part of) a program or dll. 
The hash is then compared against a hashtable in the virus software.

**Simple changes will change the hash and disable the warning.**
Virusscan technology has been standing still for many many years, despite the marketing claims of AntiVirus producers.

There is no such thing as heuristic scanning etc...

If you flip some things around so that Delphi produces different code, your hash will change and the match will go away.